# instantiate chrome object in powershell

Tags: google-chrome, powershell, instantiation

I have a powershell script which works just fine in IE however I need to also have it work in Chrome.
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
Works fine for IE.
How do I instantiate the Chrome browser?

Comment: I do not believe Chrome has provided Com objects to be used in PS.

Answer (score 38):

You can start a process by name and even pass it a parameter, like this:

```
Start-Process "chrome.exe" "www.google.com"
```

Comment: Note: you will not have the same level of control over Chrome like you do with using the New-Object cmdlet and IE.

Comment: This works perfectly. I was looking for a solution that would allow me to open chrome to a specific site as part of configuring the workstation for work and this did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Did not work for me under RDP remote app, although starting calc, i.e., `Start-Process "calc"` works fine.

Comment: @Leo,  The original question was not asked in the context of RDP.  Please reconsider your downvote.

Comment: @jim, I did not downvote. I just added a comment for others who may encounter this page.

Comment: @Leo,  My mistake.  In regards to the powershell not starting Chrome under RDP, what message does it give you?

Answer (score 4):

if you are fine with a 3rd party dll you could use Selenium which has also a Chromdriver, that gives you the same kind of control over Chrome as through InternetExplorer.Application COM

[Selenium webpage](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)

There is also a PowerShell wrapper for Selenium available on CodePlex

http://sepsx.codeplex.com/